# Is it possible to add multiple google analytics separately to a single page

Tags: html, google-analytics, google-apps-script

I need to add two google analytics to a single page

Script 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Script 2

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>
>   var _gaq = _gaq || [];
>   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-2']);
>   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
>
>   (function() {
>     var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
>     ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
>     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
>   })();
>
> </script>
> ```

Can I add these two scripts separately  to my html page.

I saw methods like combining 2 scripts

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var trackerA = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXXX-X");
   trackerA._initData();
   trackerA._trackPageview();
   var trackerB = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXXX-X");
   trackerB._initData();
   trackerB._trackPageview();
 </script>
```

My concern is, can we add scripts separately. Please help.

Comment: I'd say just try it out with two separate script tags, it might work

Comment: Have a look at this page: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/?hl=pl#MultipleCommands

Answer (score 0):

Note: `_initData()` has been deprecated.

You can use use multiple trackers at the same time by specifying a name before the function name in the _gaq.push call:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['b._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-2']);
_gaq.push(['b._trackPageview']);
```